# Paypal Restfull API, setting receiver email address

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I can receive payment using paypal rest api on my website, but how can i get these payments received by someother paypal email address.

Like people add their products on my page and once their product is sold, as soon the buyers pays, i want the money to be credited in seller's paypal account instead of my paypal account. where can i mention the seller paypal address in rest api cal so that money goes to him after the sale

secondly paypal sends the transaction time in following format
2013-03-01T22:34:35Z

what is the timezone of this time?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a post I wrote about setting the receiver of a payment with the REST APIs: https://devblog.paypal.com/setting-payee/. In essence, you just add something like the following to your transaction object:

```
payee: {
    email: 'payee@test.com'
}
```

Also, the time zone should be GMT that is being returned.

Comment: so that mean, the payee email address does not need to belong to the app owner in any way? If i am the app owner, i can get the payment sent to any seller by simply mentioning his email address in the pay field?

Comment: That's correct @Raza, it's an improvement we pushed through late last year. During my tests, I had a separate PayPal account that was not the app owner that I was able to transmit funds to. Just to note though, this is currently working for direct payments (customer to merchant), but not with the billing APIs (subscriptions).

Comment: that means, it solves the issue for merchant website owner, that they need to get money to their account and then send to seller, rather seller can directly get it from buy, all the merchant website owner doing is that hosting the product of the seller and generating the payment link and redirecting the buyer to that link?

Comment: Yes, you will basically be hosting the products on your site, and sending the money from the purchase to another merchant. The only difference in the code / setup of the site is in the addition of that payee object.

Comment: @JonathanLeBlanc SSL expired.  Also, the link does not go to the article directly.